# Why Laravel query returns empty array?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I'm using Laravel query builder to retrieve results from db but it shows me empty array but whenever i use raw query it shows me results.
Any solutions?

RAW query (showing results)

```
$work_query = 'SELECT * FROM work_availability WHERE EmployeeID = ' . $id . ' AND Position LIKE "%' . $r->position . '%" AND Type = "' . $r->first_time_type . '"';
```

Laravel Query builder (return empty array)

```
$work_first_time = DB::table('work_availability')
        ->where('EmployeeID', $r->id)
        ->where('Position', 'LIKE', " % $r->position % ")
        ->where('Type', '"'.$r->first_time_type.'"')
        ->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

1.Error is in `->where('Type', '"'.$r->first_time_type.'"')`. quotes not required in laravel
2.Erorr in  `->where('Position', 'LIKE', " % $r->position % ")`

You can use here two ways

```
->where('Position', 'like', "%{$r->position }%")
```

or

```
->where('Position', 'like', "%".$r->position."%")
```

So Final code will be

```
$work_first_time = DB::table('work_availability')
        ->where('EmployeeID', $r->id)
        ->where('Position', 'like', " %{$r->position}% ")
        ->where('Type', $r->first_time_type)
        ->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: Still gives empty array

Comment: can you show what you get in dd($r->all()); and try to use like smaller one.

Comment: [
  "id" => "1047"
  "position" => "Care Assistant,Live In"
  "first_time_days" => "Friday"
  "second_time_days" => "Saturday"
  "daysit_days" => null
  "sleepin_days" => null
  "first_time_type" => "06:45-15:00"
  "second_time_type" => "15:00-21:45"
  "other_type" => "Other"
  "daysit_type" => "DaySit"
  "sleepin_type" => "SleepIn"
  "week_type" => "Weeks"
  "waking_type" => "WakingNight"
  "other_data" => "nonef"
  "week_data" => "10"
  "AnnualLeave" => "Yes"
  "AnnualLeaveDates" => "19-10-2020,21-10-2020,23-10-2020"
]

Comment: The result of dd($r->all()); no problems with that one

Comment: okay .check $r->id dd gets value .but i am sure its there  but query is fine.better way is comment one by one where condition so you can check which one fails.

Comment: the problem is here where('Position', 'LIKE', " %{$r->position}% ")

Comment: try this ->where('Position', 'like', "%".$r->position."%")